# This is not a function; it cannot be applied

Tags: ocaml

I'm brand new to OCaml, and was trying to make a function to see if a list x was a subset of y, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I've read a bunch of similar problems, and they all list type conflict as the cause, but I'm not sure where I have any sort of conflict.

```
# let header x = List.hd x;;
val header : 'a list -> 'a = <fun>
# let matcher x y = List.mem x y;;
val matcher : 'a -> 'a list -> bool = <fun>
# let tailer x = List.tl x;;
val header : 'a list -> 'a = <fun>
# let rec sub x y =
  if ((List.length x) == 0) then true
  else if (matcher (header x) y) then sub((tailer x) y)
  else false;;
Error: This expression has type 'a list
       This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
```

In rec sub x y, I can either return 'true' for an empty list x, redo sub on the List.tl of x, aka the list without the head (from what I understand), or just return a false if I wasn't able to find the current head of x in y. The recursion would have to eventually lead to either a true or false, so I don't see where a type conflict could arise.

Comment: For best results, I'd suggest you access list elements only via pattern-matching. You may not even need to use functions from the `List` module. For example, you can check if a list is empty without computing its length using `match ... with [] -> ... | head :: tail -> ...`.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
sub((tailer x) y)
```

The outer parentheses means you're applying `y` to the result of `tailer x`. The error message tells you that this result is an `'a list`, not a function. It also means you're only passing a single argument to 'sub', the result of applying `y` to `tailer x`.

I'm not entirely sure why you believe these parentheses are necessary, but it seems likely you're confusing it with C-style function application, and simply removing them solves the error.

It might also be worth noting that, because of currying, `(tailer x) y` and `tailer x y` is equivalent. So you either mean `sub (tailer x y)` or `sub (tailer x) y`. In either case there's too many parentheses.

Comment: (In the expression `f x`, `f` is being applied to `x`. You seem to have this backwards. In `(tailer x) y`, `tailer x` is being applied to `y`.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Hmm, yeah to me it makes more sense to apply an argument to a function than to apply a function to an argument. So I would say `x` and `y` are both applied to `tailer`, rather than `tailer` being applied to `x` and  `tailer x` to `y`. I can see how theoretically the latter makes more sense, but do you think the difference is significant otherwise?